# Render a different button after onPress is invoked in React Native

Tags: android, ios, button, react-native

I have a button in my View, so when the button is pressed, I would like to hide the current button and render a new button.

```
  renderButton(item) {
      if(this.props.cartButtonPressed) {
         return <ActivityIndicator />
   }
   return <Button color ='#FFF' fontSize={12} buttonStyle={styles.button} 
               containerViewStyle={styles.buttonContainer} title='Add to cart' 
        onPress={() => this.onButtonPress(item)}/>          
   }
```

this is my code sample, but it doesn't work.

Edit #1

```
 render () {
    return (
      <View>

        <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
        <FormInput onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)} value={this.props.email}/>
        <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
        <FormInput secureTextEntry onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)} value={this.props.password}/>
        <Text style={styles.errorText}> {this.props.error} </Text>
        {this.renderButton()}

      </View>
    );
  }
 }
```

Edit #2

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  cartItems: [],
  cartButtonPressed: false
}

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
    return {
      ...state,
      cartItems: [...state.cartItems, action.payload],
      cartButtonPressed: true
    };

    default:
    return state
  }
};
```

I map my state variables to props using the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ cart }) => {
  const { cartButtonPressed } = cart;
  return {
    cartButtonPressed
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show full code please? And where did you call `renderButton(item)` function?

Comment: added my `render()` method where i call the `renderButton(item)`

Comment: i guess you need to change the this.props.cartButtonPressed to a state variable and change it on click. Props now remains the same everytime so it doesnt change when you click on it

Comment: in order to re-render your component, you will have to update state object. I am not sure how you are getting, `this.props.cartButtonPressed`. but, if define, cardButtonPressed in state and flip its value to true from false when your first button is clicked, it will re-render the view and second button should appear and first one should disappear.

Comment: the `this.props.cartButtonPressed` is a state variable. It is just been mapped as a props. I use redux to update the `cartButtonPressed` flag using a reducer whenever the button is clicked. (Edit #2)